# In PHP how to create a new directory every time?

Tags: php, shell

I have a Shell script that is calling under a PHP script :-

```
<?php
shell_exec("sh /home/folder/R.sh /home/folder/input/OM_22_3.txt 
/home/folder/output");

$directoryName = basename(getcwd());
Check if the directory already exists.
if(!is_dir($directoryName)){
Directory does not exist, so lets create it.
mkdir($directoryName, 0755);
}
?>
```

In this script R.sh is a Shell script, OM_22_3.txt is input file and output is output folder. But this program is not working. I want to make it dynamic like every time when I will run this PHP script it will generate a new output folder for result files. How can I make this dynamic?, What modification is required?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function CreateDirectory($DirName) {
    if (mkdir($DirName . date(Y-m-d), 0777)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

This will create a directory every day with date, month and year, if you want with time you can append date('h-i-s') also.

Comment: Still it is creating file in output folder

Comment: Simple, instead of checking the condition, skip it, everytime it will create new directory i.e. override existence directory.

Comment: but if I want to keep both old and new directory?

Comment: Then better create a directory with date and time. i.e each time a new directory will be created with date and time this will ensure old directory remains too and you need not to check if directory exists condition... i can help with that code if you need

Comment: Help will appreciated. Please edit this code according to time and date.